# Restart npm scripts on Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

Is there a restart button to restart npm scripts on visual studio code like the ones that exist in IntelliJ?

[image]

Until now, I need to close the terminal running the npm script and start it again.

[image]

Comment: there was a vote for this fix https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95291

Comment: It didn't get enough votes on github, and the request was closed :(